# How to abort sendAndReceive on MessageConversionException

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm using spring-amqp's (latest version) `rabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive(exchange, routingKey, message)` method for sending messages. **RabbitTemplate** is configured with **Jackson2JsonMessageConverter**.

If I send a malformed json, I can see that message conversion fails with `org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Failed to convert Message content`, as expected.

However, the **sendAndReceive** method doesn't abort and continues execution until a replyTimeout is hit.
To compare, if there is an error in my **@RabbitListener** annotated method, then **sendAndReceive** aborts instantly and returns the exception.

Is there any way to tell spring to abort **sendAndReceive** in case of conversion exceptions?

```
2021-05-18 17:07:38.188 WARN  [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#8-1] [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler] :: Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1746)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1636)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1551)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1539)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1530)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1474)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:967)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:913)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1194)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Failed to convert Message content
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:294)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:271)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:251)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.extractMessage(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:342)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter.extractPayload(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:325)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.fromMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:132)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:207)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:134)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1632)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (String)"{sd}"; line: 1, column: 81]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1851)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:707)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:632)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipComma(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2324)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextFieldName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:921)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:525)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:377)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4526)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3468)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.convertBytesToObject(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:351)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.convertContent(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:321)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:291)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
2021-05-18 17:07:38.188 WARN  [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#8-1] [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler$DefaultExceptionStrategy] :: Fatal message conversion error; message rejected; it will be dropped or routed to a dead letter exchange, if so configured: (Body:'{sd}' MessageProperties [headers={centreId=0, deliveryTypeId=null, path=/somePath, privileges=[], salespointId=0, insuranceId=null, promoter=null, userName=null, parameters={}, userId=null, superCentreId=0}, correlationId=1, replyTo=amq.rabbitmq.reply-to.g1h2AA5yZXBseUA4NzA3MTY3MAAAaScAAAABYJ9TZA==.YoDsH6nkpNiLYvA4h8716g==, contentType=application/json, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=someExchange, receivedRoutingKey=someKey, deliveryTag=1, consumerTag=amq.ctag-lHGwtgImO4ohGFCAHuKkLg, consumerQueue=someQueue])
2021-05-18 17:07:38.188 ERROR [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#8-1] [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer] :: Execution of Rabbit message listener failed, and the error handler threw an exception
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Error Handler converted exception to fatal
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.handleError(ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java:146)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeErrorHandler(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1436)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1720)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1495)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:967)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:913)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1194)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1746)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1636)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1551)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1539)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1530)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1474)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Failed to convert Message content
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:294)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:271)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:251)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.extractMessage(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:342)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter.extractPayload(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:325)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.fromMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:132)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:207)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:134)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1632)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (String)"{sd}"; line: 1, column: 81]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1851)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:707)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:632)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipComma(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2324)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextFieldName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:921)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:525)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:377)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4526)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3468)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.convertBytesToObject(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:351)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.convertContent(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:321)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:291)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

***EDIT 1:*** It seems this is a bug in `spring-amqp`. You can follow the status of this issue [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1339).

***EDIT 2:*** Fixed in `spring-amqp 2.3.9`.

Comment: If you use `RabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive()`, then you already have a message and the mentioned converted is not involved. So, something is off from your explanation. Please, consider to share some code to let us to reproduce the issue on our side.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Not sure what you mean by that. I included the stacktrace for clarity. This exception is expected, it should be thrown, because I'm passing a malformed json in the message body. The question is why sendAndReceive doesn't return immediately when such exception is thrown.

Comment: Your stack trace doesn't have any `template` references. So, your problem happened on the server side when there it is exactly a listener as we see in that stack trace. So, it is misleading to point only to the template when it sends a message over there broker without problems. The consumer side cannot deal with that malformed JSON somehow. And answering to your question: no template cannot return immediately because an exception is out of its control at that point. Please, consider to revise your question to let us better to understand what is going on.

Comment: @ArtemBilan The consumer, which is annotated with **@RabbitListener** isn't invoked at all when such conversion exceptions happen. As I understand, this exception occurs before the message reaches the consumer. Please have a look at this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/issues/58). I have the same situation as described in this issue. But in my case, I'm using the rpc pattern and I need to somehow signal to sendAndReceive to return immediately if an exception occurs and not wait for the full replyTimeout duration to elapse (which eventually returns null).

Comment: I think you mean it doesn't reach listener method because it cannot be converted properly on the consumer. But still it is on the other side of the network from the producer. I don't mind that we probably need to improve this error scenario, but you should understand that it has nothing to do with the producer side since it does not fail to send a message to the broker over the network.

Comment: I'm not saying there is a problem on the producer side. The message is indeed sent successfully. It is the consumer side that fails to process the message due to conversion issues. However in this case consumer processing error is out my control, since it happens before it reaches my @RabbitListener annotated method. It's some kind of lower-level container error. So I just need to know if there is any way (through some setting or some error handler) to abort the sendAndReceive method, so that I don't have to wait for the reply timeout to elapse.

Comment: @ArtemBilan The way I see it is sendAndReceive doesn't react to this exception and continues waiting for a reply from the consumer, which never arrives, so sendAndReceive just keeps on waiting until replyTimeout passes and then returns null.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I added a [minimal reproducer](https://github.com/nkvaratskhelia/rabbit-demo) to help you better understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I see what is going on. We fail on the `AbstractMessageListenerContainer` which does not know yet that our `MessageListener` is about a request-reply behavior. So, it silently handles an exception via its default `ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler`, which, in turn, throws an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` and that's it. The listener container comes back to the main loop for the next message.

You probably have to implement your own `ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler` overriding its:

```
/**
 * Called when a message with a fatal exception has an {@code x-death} header, prior
 * to discarding the message. Subclasses can override this method to perform some
 * action, such as sending the message to a parking queue.
 * @param failed the failed message.
 * @since 2.3
 */
protected void handleDiscarded(Message failed) {
```

To send a reply back with an error message.

Feel free to raise a GitHub issue, so we will think together how to deal with such a situation on the common level.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1339